# No connection via Airport Express in bridge mode

Tags: connection, bridge, airport-express

I have trouble connecting to my wired network via an Airport Express. I would like to have the Airport Express just operate as a bridge -- i.e. as an access point. I have set up the Airport Express to talk 802.11n @ 5 GHz, getting its IPv4 connection from my wired network's DHCP, and acting in bridge only mode.

The wired network is constituted by a ZyXEL P-2812HNU-F1 VDSL-router (acting router, DHCP-server and switch).

However, though my wired network works just fine on its own, and the Airport Express wireless network works just fine on its own (I can connect easily to the Airport Express via the Airport Utility), the connection from the Airport Express wireless network to the wired network (and the Internet), is shaky to say the least -- most of the time there is no connection at all (and the Internet icon in Airport Utility is accompanied by an orange light), then there might be a short interval with a connection (green light, but the interval is not even long enough to completely fetch a Google search result page), and then a few more minutes with no connection.

Any ideas and/or experiences?